# Replace string with substring that is html safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say that I have a string

```
string_with_url = 'Random text https://myurl.com'
```

Is it possible to wrap the url with an anchor tag and only make the wrapped text html safe?

Currently I have to do the following

```
def add_anchor(message)
    url_regex = %r{(?:https?)://\S+}i
    string_with_url.gsub url_regex, '<a href="\0" target="_blank">\0</a>'

render add_anchor(string_with_url).html_safe
```

Even though I am only adding the anchor tag here, I am forced to make the wrong string html safe.

Comment: That'll break down on things like `https://example.com/"><script>hostile_script()</script>`

Comment: Looks like you want something like the [`autolink` gem](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink).

Comment: I think you may be under the impression that `html_safe` makes the string html safe ... it does not ... it is a mechanism to flag that a string is html safe and prevents it from being html escaped.

Comment: Does auto_link not do the same thing here?